# What is "__Deferred_Default_Marker__"?

Tags: r, r-s4

I've been examining this rather old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709933/adding-s4-dispatch-to-base-r-s3-generic) and playing around with different functions and classes. As it can be seen below, a single call to `setGeneric` can result in some notation I've never met before in R.

```
setGeneric("+", function(e1, e2) standardGeneric("+"),
           useAsDefault=base::`+`)

#Creating a new generic function for ‘+’ in the global environment
#[1] "+"

1 + 1
#`__Deferred_Default_Marker__`
```

So, what does "__Deferred_Default_Marker__" mean? Is it an "error" or some sort of "undefined behaviour"? FWIW, `rm("+")` restores the operator and `1 + 1` is again `2`.

Comment: ["You cannot (and never need to) create an explicit generic version of the primitive functions in the base package. ... See the section on Primitive Functions below."](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setGeneric.html)

Comment: @Roland Thank you; there's also said "Note that S4 methods can only be set on those primitives which are ‘internal generic’, plus %*%." I knew that I'm doing something forbidden and expected some sort of error or warning, and I'd still like to know what is that "marker" entity.

Comment: I'd suggest to test if this can be reproduced with R-devel and write a feature request. I believe `setGeneric` should give an error in this case.