# Creating an S4 Method named `Median`

Tags: r, r-s4, r-s3

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100856/combining-s4-and-s3-methods-in-a-single-function), the top answers describes a good way to make a method dispatch on both S3 and S4 objects. However, that way only works when both methods have the same signature.

Is there a way to create an S4 method for `median` with a different signature?

For example, the following does not work:

```
setGeneric("median")
median.Foo <- function(arg1, arg2, ...){}
setMethod("median", "Foo", median.Foo)
```

When installing the libary, there is an error saying that formal arguments are missing, `x` and `na.rm`, which are the arguments for the original median function.

I would like to avoid the solution at the top of author's post.

Comment: That does not look like a correct method for creating an S4 function. The formalism `fn_name.class_name <- function(...) {body}` is for defining S3 functions. Read `?setMethod` and look at the examples there.

Comment: I was just replicating part of the code in the link. Normally I don't structure my function names like that.

Comment: You need to look at the answer by Marin Morgan (and on the help page). He knows more than the questioner.

Comment: In Marin's code, he calls `setMethod` with a third argument in the form `function.class". In this case I want a S4 method for `median` for class `Foo` and `median.default` (the built in S3 method) called otherwise.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`setGeneric("median")` creates an S4 generic with the same signature as stats::median

```
> stats::median
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

so you could write methods

```
median.Foo <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {}
setMethod(median, "Foo", median.Foo)
```

I *think* the package check message would be addressed by

```
setGeneric("median", function(arg1, arg2, ...) standardGeneric("median"))
```

and then as you write. But probably that is **a bad idea** because now the S3 methods are masked by your function

```
> median(1:5)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'median' for signature '"integer"'
```

I think you're stuck with the default arguments or a modified function name. The title of your post says `Median` and R is case sensitive... but that's also a bad idea.

Comment: OK, a bit of a bummer than I'm stuck with default arguments. What I did was mask the default `median` function (in the `stats` package) using an S4 method with a `...` construct in the argument list and then just dispatch to the built in `median` like the OP did in the link. When I introduce the library in R, it gives me a warning saying that `The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’: median`. Is there a way to make so such a message doesn't occur? `suppressWarnings` doesn't work with the `library` function.

Comment: `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` quietens the message (not a warning, technically), but the message is not incorrect so...