# Dispatch a custom method on S3*data.frame

Tags: r, r-s3

I would like to define my own behavior (method) for the multiplication of a
data.frame with an object of a new S3 class. But I can't figure out how to get
methods dispatch to find my method. Is there a way?

First, I define S3 objects 'a' (oldClass "A") and 'df' (oldClass "data.frame"):

```
a <- 4
oldClass(a) <- "A"
df <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)
```

I then use trace(Ops.data.frame, edit=TRUE) to add print("Ops.data.frame") at the
first line. This way, I know when Ops.data.frame gets called. Here's a demonstration:

```
a*df
# [1] "Ops.data.frame"
# x  y
# 1 4 12
# 2 8 16
```

I could define an S3 method for class "A".

```
Ops.A <- function(e1, e2) {
  print("Ops.A")
  oldClass(e1) <- oldClass(e1)[oldClass(e1) != "A"]
  oldClass(e2) <- oldClass(e2)[oldClass(e2) != "A"]
  callGeneric(e1, e2)
}
```

This gets called for a*a but not for a*df:

```
# This successfully calls Ops.A
a*a
# [1] "Ops.A"
# [1] 16

# But this throws an error
a*df
# Error in a * df : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# In addition: Warning message:
#   Incompatible methods ("Ops.A", "Ops.data.frame") for "*"
```

So that won't work.

```
remove(Ops.A)
```

What about using an S4 method instead? This requires defining the S4 class "A", but usually an S3 object with oldClass "A" will still be found by S4 dispatch.

```
setClass("A", list("numeric")) # Required to define a method for "A"
setGeneric("ATypicalMethod", function(e1, e2) {print("ATypicalMethod - default")})
setMethod("ATypicalMethod", signature=c("A","A"), function(e1, e2) {print("ATypicalMethod - A,A")})
ATypicalMethod(a,a)
# [1] "ATypicalMethod - A,A"
```

However, that doesn't work for Ops.

```
setMethod("Ops", signature=c("A","data.frame"), function(e1, e2) {
  print("Ops(A,data.frame)")
  callGeneric(e1@.Data, e2)
})
# Nope - when the scalar is an S3 object, we never find Ops(A,data.frame):
a*df
# [1] "Ops.data.frame"
# x  y
# 1 4 12
# 2 8 16
```

This behavior of a*df is explained by Martin Morgan 
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101238/3203184) and ?Methods, who say that if
the S3 generic is called directly, then the S4 methods will never be found;
this appears to be happening in a*df because both a and df are S3 objects.

And it doesn't help any to also call `setOldClass`; the problem is not that the S3 object *can't be recognized* by S4 methods dispatch, but that it *isn't looked for* when two S3 objects are passed to methods like `*`. In these cases the S3 generic is invoked directly, and no amount of S4 labeling will lead to S4 dispatch.

```
setOldClass("A", S4Class="A")
a*df
# [1] "Ops.data.frame"
# x  y
# 1 4 12
# 2 8 16
```

So now I'm at a loss. I've found no way to get `*` to discover an S4 method for my S3 object, and no way to write an S3 method that supersedes the data.frame method.

If I were willing to make the scalar an S4 object, I could get the dispatch I want:

```
a <- new("A", 4)
a*df
# [1] "Ops(A,data.frame)"
# [1] "Ops.data.frame"
# x  y
# 1 4 12
# 2 8 16
```

But I'm really hoping to keep 'a' as an S3 object. Is there a way to both (1)
let 'a' be S3 and (2) define my own method for Ops('A', 'data.frame')?

Comment: `help("groupGeneric")`: "If a method is found for just one argument or the same method is found for both, it is used. If different methods are found, there is a warning about ‘incompatible methods’: in that case or if no method is found for either argument the internal method is used."

Comment: @Roland - right. So is there a way around that, or do I have to give up?

Comment: I believe you can't do this with S3. I don't know enough about S4 to fully answer the question.

Comment: @Roland - OK, that's a useful partial answer. Thanks.

Comment: what if you promote your S3 to S4 using setOldCLass ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Karl, but I've added another paragraph and code chunk above (starting with "And it doesn't help any to also call setOldClass") to explain why setOldClass won't help.

Comment: I guess you have considered using custom operators...

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't be useful here. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

very ugly way: override the '*' function

```
a <- 4
oldClass(a) <- "A"
df <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)

my_add_df <- function(e1, e2) {
  print('my_add_df')
  print(e1)
  print(e2)
}

`*` <- function(e1, e2) {
  if (inherits(e1, 'A') && inherits(e2, 'data.frame'))
    my_add_df(e1, e2)
  else 
    .Primitive("*")(e1, e2)
}

a <- 4
oldClass(a) <- "A"
df <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)

my_add_df <- function(e1, e2) {
  print('my_add_df')
  print(e1)
  print(e2)
}

`*` <- function(e1, e2) {
  if (inherits(e1, 'A') && inherits(e2, 'data.frame'))
    my_add_df(e1, e2)
  else 
    .Primitive("*")(e1, e2)
}
```